# How to get current hour in android?

Tags: android

Time class is no longer possible to use. 
I want to ask you, how to detect in app 3-4am?
I need that to set up for example night mode in my app.

Can you give me some example how to do it?

Answer (score 71):

Instead of using `Time` (because Time class was deprecated in API level 22.) you can use `Calendar` for getting current hour

```
val rightNow = Calendar.getInstance()
val currentHourIn24Format: Int =rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) // return the hour in 24 hrs format (ranging from 0-23)
val currentHourIn12Format: Int = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR) // return the hour in 12 hrs format (ranging from 0-11)
```

Comment: `rightNow.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` in case you need to get time on Specific Timezone

Answer (score 13):

We can use the `Calendar` class to get a format like "HH:mm:ss"

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour24hrs = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); 
int hour12hrs = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR); 
int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 
int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND); 
System.out.println("Current hour 24hrs format:  " + hour24hrs + ":" + minutes +":"+ seconds);
System.out.println("Current hour 12hrs format:  " + hour12hrs + ":" + minutes +":"+ seconds);
```

---

Other option using the `Date` class and applying the format `"HH:mm:ss"`:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String dateformatted = dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(dateformatted);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use following methods:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH", Locale.US);
String hour = format.format(new Date());

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int hourOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```